# Disable Lazy-Loading in doctrine 2 and ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

actually i'm totaly new in doctrine 2 , i'm using it in a project by zendframework 2 , what i'm looking for is to disable the lazy-loading in doctrine 2 , i've this way for the custom queries :

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('ed')
                ->from('Application\Entity\Object', 'ob')
                ->innerJoin('ob.fkLogin', 'lg')
                ->where("lg.state= 'valid'");

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true);
        $objects= $query->getResult();
```

it's by using the setHint for the query , i'm asking how can i do the same for : fecthAll and findBy , find , for example for this query :

```
   $object = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('\Application\Entity\Object')->find($id);
```

Thanks.

Comment: no one knows how ?!!!!

Comment: http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/some-doctrine-2-best-practices/

Comment: It doesn't exist in that tuto , i've already check it out...

Comment: Have a closer look at #2

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Doctrine 2 can the Fetch Mode (Eager/Lazy etc.) be changed at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939339/in-doctrine-2-can-the-fetch-mode-eager-lazy-etc-be-changed-at-runtime)

Comment: i found it in that question , thanks .